# Открытие внешних приложений через Electron.js?

Tags: javascript, electron

Всем привет! Возможно ли с помощью Electron.js открывать приложения?

```
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;
var runLibreOffice = function() {
    exec('C:/Program Files/WinRAR/WinRAR.exe', function(err, data) {
        console.log(err)
        console.log(data.toString());
    });
}
```

Если использовать такой код (выше), то ошибку выдаёт **"Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at renderer.js:57"**

Comment: этот код для «серверной части»

Answer (score 0):

```js
var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
var commandtoRun = "C:/Program Files/WinRAR/WinRAR.exe"; 
oShell.ShellExecute(commandtoRun, "", "", "open", "1");
```